# Подсвечивание карточки товара

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

На https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/noutbuki/?sorting=price_asc&f=discount.any%2Crating.any- карточки товаров разграничены линиями-разделителями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Каким образом можно реализовать линию-разделитель между карточками товаров?

При наведении на карточку товара происходит увеличение высоты карточки и ее подсвечивание (окружение ее серой полоской высотой 1-3px).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Каким образом можно реализовать подсвечивание карточки товара?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Линия разделитель в данном случае

```
border-top: 1px solid #dfdfe1;
```

2 Для подсвечивания элемента используется здесь `box-shadow`

```
:hover {
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgb(30 31 33 / 12%);
    border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: а что такое `rgb(30 31 33 / 12%)`?

Comment: Цвет в формате rgb, 12% это прозрачность